# Django - Reuse an annotated count

Tags: django, django-orm

I have a model that allows me to log errors with a hash that I generate, so the same errors have the same hash so I am able to group and count them. The model looks something like this.

```
class ErrorLog(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True, db_index=True)
    log = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    log_hash = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
```

In my view, I perform the following query to count the errors by hash.

```
def get(self, request):
    qs = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
    total_errors = qs.count()

    qs = qs.values(
        'log_hash', 'log'
    ).annotate(
        error_count=Count('log_hash')
    ).annotate(
        percentage_of_occurrence=Concat(
            Cast(
                funcs.Round(
                    (F('error_count') / total_errors) * 100, 1
                ), CharField()
            ), Value('%')
        )
    )
```

This works like a charm, because I can get my results back just as I want them.

```
"results": [
        {
            "error_count": 2,
            "percentage_of_occurrence": "50.0%",
            "log_hash": "8f7744ba51869f93ce990c67bd8d3544",
            "log": "Error 1"
        },
        {
            "error_count": 1,
            "percentage_of_occurrence": "25.0%",
            "log_hash": "de54a1e3be2cab4d04d8c61f538a71df",
            "log": "Error 2"
        },
        {
            "error_count": 1,
            "percentage_of_occurrence": "25.0%",
            "log_hash": "05988dc15543ef06e803a930923d11d4",
            "log": "Error 3"
        }
    ]
```

Here comes the problem, this is REALLY slow on a large table, so after inspecting the SQL generated I saw one problem. I am counting 2 times, one to get the `error_count`, and another one to calculate the `percentage_of_occurrence`.

```
SELECT `errorlog`.`log_hash`, `errorlog`.`log`, COUNT(`errorlog`.`log_hash`) AS `error_count`, 
((COUNT(`errorlog`.`log_hash`) / ) * 100) AS `percentage_of_occurrence` 
FROM `errorlog` 
GROUP BY `errorlog`.`log_hash`, `errorlog`.`log`
ORDER BY `error_count` DESC
```

Is there any way I can reuse the first count to calculate the `percentage_of_occurrence` without having to count again? Also, I am not very savvy on SQL, but would it be better if the `log_hash` column was indexed?

Comment: Are you sure that this is the issue? I think the text processing is more likely a candidate for the inefficiency. Likely it makes more sense to do that at the serializer side. After all if the `Count(..)` is really the slow part, it would at most *double* the amount of time the query takes.

Comment: To be honest, I don't really know if the issue is the text processing, probably you are right. I'll remove the text processing and just output 25.0 and 50.0 as floats. Anyway, my question stand still. Is it possible to reuse the COUNT?

Comment: Furthermore it looks more that you should construct an index (likely a `ForeignKey` is better here), to avoid the `GROUP BY` to slow down.

Comment: No, it's not possible, right now Django's ORM  is not smart enough to realize this and repeats the subquery everywhere